# Dynamically populate select input without duplicate values using JSTL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

In my list called "rooms" there is a collection of objects with a property called "floor" which is an integer.

I am trying to populate a select with a list of those floors but I cannot work out how to remove duplicates.

Can I use a `<c:if>` within the loop or is there another method to ensure no duplicates?

What I have so far:

```
<select id="floorFilter">
    <option value=""></option>
    <c:forEach var="room" items="${rooms}">
        <c:if test="">
            <option value="${room.floor}">${room.floor}</option>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

**EDIT:** Each 'room' has a 'floor' property assigned to it by the user when it is created. There is no collection of 'floors' to reference against so it is not possible to remove duplicates from the backend.

Comment: Remove duplicates in the backend.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Each 'room' has a 'floor' property assigned to it by the user when it is created. There is no collection of 'floors' to reference against so it is not possible to remove duplicates from the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I will not suggest you to do this** but here is some code to achieve what you want:

```
<select id="floorFilter">
    <option value=""></option>
    <c:forEach var="room" items="${rooms}" varStatus="status">
        <c:set var="floorAlreadyExists" value="${false}" />
        <c:if test="${(status.index - 1) > 0}">
            <c:forEach var="previousRoom" items="${rooms}" begin="0" end="${status.index - 1}" varStatus="inner">
                <c:if test="${room.floor == previousRoom.floor}">
                    <c:set var="floorAlreadyExists" value="${true}" />
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not floorAlreadyExists}">
            <option value="${room.floor}">${room.floor}</option>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

There are at least wo problems with this code:

1. it's verbose and hard to understand
2. the values are the floor values of your rooms in whatever order you have the rooms. I assume your want the floors in ascending order not in whatever order you get them from the rooms. You could sort them somehow in the JSP but that will add a lot of additional code so we are back to number 1.

**What I suggest you to do** is what @Alex suggested also: do this in the backend.

> There is no collection of 'floors' to reference against so it is not possible to remove duplicates from the backend.

You don't need to work exclusively on the domain entities. You can build additional helper structures for the view only. Loop through your collection of rooms and build a collection of distinct floors, sort the collection of floors, then have your `forEach` written over the collection of floors instead, something like this:

```
<select id="floorFilter">
    <option value=""></option>
    <c:forEach var="floor" items="${floors}">
        <option value="${floor}">${floor}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

This way the JSP is easy to understand, the code in the backend will be Java, so less verbose and easier to fallow.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. Although your first solution works, I agree that it is not suitable for the reasons you mentioned. I'm still new to Java and JSTL and was hoping there was a simpler solution. I'll look for an alternative method.